# Why is ויהי נועם said after הנני מוכןs?

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, tehilim-psalms, provenance

Most (but not all) Siddurim have the פסוק of [ויהי נועם](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6_%D7%99%D7%96) at the end of הנני מוכןs (such as before ספירת העומר, before the ארבע כוסות, or before בדיקת חמץ).

Where does this practice come from and why is it done?

Comment: The title asks why it's said (seeking a reason), and the question asks where it comes from (seeking a provenance). Which do you mean? Or both?

Comment: @msh: Both, ideally.

Comment: We're talking about before ספירת העומר, right?

Comment: @jake: Among other things.  For example, before the ארבע כוסות, as well as ביעור and בדיקת חמץ.

Comment: It would be good to include this clarifying and contextual information into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pasuk of ויהי נועם concludes, not the הנני מוכן exactly, but more specifically, the paragraph of לשם יחוד.  This paragraph states intent to perform the mitzvot in conjunction with uniting the Holy One, blessed be He, and His Sh'china.  This is a Kabbalistic declaration, in accord with the customs of the Ari.

I'm certainly not qualified to answer Kabbalah questions, so I don't know the reason for concluding that paragraph with ויהי נועם.

In Sephardic congregations, there is a similar paragraph before Shacharit, Mincha, and Arvit, as well as before Birkat HaMazon and other mitzvot.

Comment: I think that's exactly it. Moshe said this pasuk to ask that "the Shechinah should rest on the work of your hands" (Rashi to Ex. 39:32), so when we invoke the "unification of G-d with His Shechinah," we ask for the same thing.

Comment: There is a Zohar about this, just can't remember where.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to help us to accomplish the *mitsva* 
this *passuk* has been said by *Moshe Rabbenu* (to be confirmed) but I cannot remember the reasons :(

The *Mishna brura* in *Hilkhot Shoffar* relates a story that one *Tokea* didn't manage to blow *Shoffar* then said this *passuk* and the sound goes.

Comment: Correct; it was said by משה.  (It's the last פסוק in תפילה למשה)